# text iterator and string

Tags: java

i wonder if there is anyway to convert a **string** into a **text iterator** then removing any desired tokens? supposed the string comes from a *node's text content*, then want to look for specific words and then removing them.

```
Set<String> Words = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("useless words.txt"));
for(String line;(line = br.readLine()) != null;)
   stopWords.add(line.trim().toString());

br.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [String replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: but as you can see, there is already a file filled by a group of words, how to make an regex out of it?

Comment: so you mean i make a iteration on the file then check the string with the words one by one?

Answer (score -1):

Java's rexex facility is well suited for this.

Your regex pattern might look something like this...  "\w+" The best reference for patterns is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

There's an example in the matcher section of [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html) that shows how to use regex patterns and matchers to replace text. Once you found a match, you could consult a hashmap of words to censor.